# White noise generator for Windows

Tags: windows, audio, offline, noise-generator

I am looking for a small app that runs in the background and generates a continuous [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:White-noise-sound-20sec-mono-44100Hz.ogg) (or blue noise or whatever; super if it lets you choose).

It should be a software or an application that works offline.

Optionally if it has the following feature/s, all the better:

- global hotkeys
- separate volume control (from the main)
- free/open source

For Windows (8).

Comment: ``It should be a software or an application`` Does this mean that mp3 tracks wouldn't fit?

Comment: @Timmy Exactly! I actually already do have a good mp3 white noise, but I don't wanna have to use my media player to play it, as I want to keep it free for playing songs on top of the white noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu) is a Music Programming Language that can generate any sound, including white noise.

1. Download and install ChucK: http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/release
2. Copy this code to a file `white-noise.ck`

   ```
   Noise n => BiQuad f => dac;
   0.99 => f.prad;
   0.05 => f.gain;
   1    => f.eqzs;
   0.00 => float t;
   while(true)
       5::ms => now;
   ```

   (checkout some other samples http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples)
3. Run `chuck white-noise.ck` from command-line.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) can generate and play white, pink and brown noise.

I mention it as in the comments you said you want to keep your media player free, so you could generate some noise in Audacity, play it there and also play your regular media in your media player?

[image: Audacity menu screenshot]
[image: Audacity Noise Generator screenshot]